Unable to run supabase edge functions locally
I have a simple edge functions script to run a prompt on the Gemini model and output back the result. Having used the debugger, the problem occurs at the code which listens to requests. The debugger mentions that there is a process already running at the port and hence there is an error.
Error at the terminal where I run the cURL command to post the request locally
{"code":"BOOT_ERROR","message":"Worker failed to boot (please check logs)"}%
Error at the debugger
error: Uncaught (in promise) AddrInUse: Address already in use (os error 48)
    const listener = Deno.listen({
                          ^
    at Object.listen (ext:deno_net/01_net.js:534:35)
    at Server.listenAndServe (https://deno.land/std@0.180.0/http/server.ts:182:27)
    at serve (https://deno.land/std@0.180.0/http/server.ts:604:20)
    at startServer (file:///Users/shlokjain/Documents/dev/beacon/supabase/functions/essay-prompt/index.ts:9:19) /* point to serve function call */
    at file:///Users/shlokjain/Documents/dev/beacon/supabase/functions/essay-prompt/index.ts:66:1

code in the script
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.180.0/http/server.ts";

const portsToTry = [54321, 8080, 8081];

async function startServer() {
    for (const port of portsToTry) {
        try {
            await serve(async (req) => {
                // code

                return new Response(JSON.stringify(data), { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'} })
            }, { port })
            console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
            break;
        } catch (err) {
            if (err instanceof Deno.errors.AddrInUse) {
                console.error(`Port ${port} is already in use`);
                continue;
            } else {
                throw err;
            }
        }
    }
}

startServer();
console.log("Hello from Functions!");

cURL command to request
curl -i --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:54321/functions/v1/essay-prompt' \
    --header 'Authorization: Bearer API_KEY' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{"essayPrompt":"Functions"}'


I have the same error {"code":"BOOT_ERROR","message":"Worker failed to boot (please check logs)"}% after restarting my supabase start. However, console logs show failed to create the graph. I reran the supabase function deploy and it works. Perhaps have to reinstall packages?

Why are you trying ports and logging the errors? you should not be using 54321 since this is the port your local Supabase setup runs on. Please take a look at example edge functions in the Supabase docs to see how they should be composed.
